# inotify watch limit reached

Tags: 20.04, systemd, inotify

I receive the following message when I attempt to restart smbd.  I understand that inotify has something to do with watching for changes in the filesystem, but I'm not sure where to start in troubleshooting or diagnosing this issue.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
$ sudo systemctl restart smbd.service
Failed to add a watch for /run/systemd/ask-password: inotify watch limit reached
```

I also checked the following which I believe is related:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
8192
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04.4 server that number is 248335. Do `sudo systemctl status smbd` and look at logs in `/var/log/samba`. increase log level in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`